# express js connection pooling not working with remote mysql server

Tags: node.js, express

When I'm trying to connect with remote `mysql` server it won't connect

{"error":true,"message":"Error occurredError: connect ETIMEDOUT"}

but its works with a local `mysql` server.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Here is some relevant code:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 1000,
  acquireTimeout: 1000,
  timeout: 1000,
  host: 'remotemysqlserver.net',
  port: '3346',
  user: 'jone',
  password: 'jone123',
  database: 'test',
  debug: true,
  multipleStatements: true
});
```

but works like this

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({

  host: 'remotemysqlserver.net',

  user: 'jone',

  password: 'jone123',

  database: 'test',

});
```

Comment: what exception/error do you have?

Comment: Is you remote server allows remote mysql connections. Please check for that

Comment: yes it is allowed to remote connections